# ASP.NET manage Message Box position with multiple display screens

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have built a web application for users who normally use 2 display monitors. When the application browser is moved to the secondary screen, all message boxes continue to be displayed on the primary screen. Is there a way in ASP.NET to "tie" the message box to the display screen where the browser is currently open? I am using ASP.NET 4.5.1 with VB

Comment: What kind op message box are you using? The javascript alerts and modal popups that i know of all stay confined within the browser window.

Comment: I use VB MsgBox. Basically, when a user clicks on a button, the code behind evaluates whether all conditions are met to perform the action and displays a message if the conditions are not met.

Comment: `MsgBox` is not meant for websites. Start using a modal popup like [Jquery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). But there are may others.

Comment: Thank you - I was able to create dialog boxes using ajax